# How add two scripts on actor Unreal Engine 4

Tags: unreal-engine4

How add two scripts on actor Unreal Engine 4, in Unity this easy, just drag script and drop on panel components, or how do subobject this actor. Sorry for my bad english.

Because when I write a script and make a blueprint based on it, as I understand it, only 1 script is processed, let's say the actor moves, but I also need to make a separate script for interacting with other objects, how to add a second script to the actor I need, in Everything is very simple in Unity, I wrote a script and crawled to the object, there is something that is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create `Actor Component` class and then attach it to your actor/pawn/character.

Comment: I don't really understand you, in Unity everything is simple, I wrote a script and added it as an additional component, and in Unreal Engine 4 I don’t understand how to do it, because this does not work here, when I just create a script and create a Blueprint based on it , then I don't understand how and where to add additional scripts to this object. Maybe there is an article or video, if there are any, please give me on this topic, because I can't find the information I need

Comment: @danil2283376 See the **Where are my components?** section [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/GettingStarted/FromUnity/index.html#wherearemycomponents?)